# Can't see my label and layout in MainWindow

Tags: c++, qt, layout

```
delete layout();

QGridLayout *gridLayout = new QGridLayout(this);

int cont = 0;
for (Category c : categories) {
    cont++;

    QVBoxLayout *verticalLayout;
    verticalLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
    gridLayout->setSpacing(cont);
    gridLayout->addLayout(verticalLayout, 0, cont - 1);

    QLabel *l;
    l = new QLabel();
    l->setText(c.getName());
    l->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    verticalLayout->addWidget(l);
}
```

In `mainWindow`, I want to add one `gridLayout` and `verticalLayout` with a label when using `for` cycle in my `categories`

Comment: do not delete your layout. The owner will take care of it as soon as you attach a new layout. this is unsafe.

Comment: Since you didnt provide a compilable souce code I assume the mistake is, that you attach your layout to the QMainWindow and not its central widget.

Comment: @Lifeisabug you're right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't set the layout to any widget. You have to call function ***setLayout(gridLayout)*** for the widget you want to apply it on. Hope it helps

Comment: thanks!! I solve in this way `QGridLayout *gridLayout = new QGridLayout();
    centralWidget()->setLayout(gridLayout);`

Comment: it is also incorrect. you DO NOT have to call setLayout if the layouts parent is the widget you want to add the layout to. In this case he simply chose the wrong widget (QMainWindow instead of its central widget)

Comment: @Lifeisabug is right. I don't know if it's really incorrect or maybe simply redundant. In my project I usually create layouts dinamically (heap) without passing any parent, because it's automatically setted when function setLayout is called. For more detailed explanation you can take a look to Qt docs (maybe you have already done) at this link http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/layout.html, in particular sections "Introduction" and "Tips for Using Layouts". Buon lavoro